# Mapping over array returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Keypad` component, each time I press a button it should add that button's value to an array:

```
var keys = this.props.keys.map(function(k, index){
        return (
            <tr className="button-row" key={index}>
                <td>
                    <button
                        className="keypad-buttons"
                        onClick={self.props.number.bind(null, k.k)}
                        >{k.k}</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
```

In my main `App` component I have a method for adding the numbers entered by `Keypad` so that I can map over them and display them in the `textArea` of 
my `Screen` component. Here is the relevant part of `App`:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return {numbers: []}
},
addNumber: function(num){
  var number = [
    {
      n: num
    }
 ]
  this.setState({
  numbers: this.state.numbers.concat(number)
})
},
```

In `Screen` component I am trying to map over the props received from `App` like this:

```
var pinNumbers = this.props.pin.map(function(num, index){
        return (
                <span key={index}>{num.n}</span>

                )
    }).join(' ')
```

And then display that in `textArea` by doing `value={pinNumbers}`. So if I type 1 2 3 on the keypad, it should map over the array of objects and display each of those values (123) in the `textArea` of my `Screen` component; instead, it displays [object Object] and I cannot figure out why. Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/PzZWJJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this code

```
var pinNumbers = this.props.pin.map(function(num, index){
        return (
                <span key={index}>{num.n}</span>    
                )
    }).join(' ');
```

It contains JSX. Let's desugar JSX to see what actually happens in that snippet.

`<span key={index}>{num.n}</span>` will be transpiled to

```
React.createElement(
  "span",
  { key: index },
  num.n
);
```

by Babel. You can verify this in online [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-1&code=%3Cspan%20key%3D%7Bindex%7D%3E%7Bnum.n%7D%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%20%20%20%0D%0A).

Hence, you have an array of React Elements which you convert to strings (receiving obvious `[Object object]`) and join with spaces.

Actually, your attempt to add spans doesn't make sense because you can not embed HTML formatting into textareas. This piece works for me

```
var pinNumbers = this.props.pin.map(function(num, index){
  return num.n; 
}).join(' ');
```