# Array .map() is returning HTML [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make simple animation text in React and JavaScript and my problem is that after mapping array with letters result in HTML what I get is `<span>[Object object]</span>`.
Someone can explain what I do wrong.

```
animation = () => {
  let text = document.querySelector(".hi");
  let leterArr = [...text.textContent];
  text.textContent = "";
  leterArr.map(char => {
    return (text.innerHTML += "<span>" +{char} +"</span>")
  })
}
```

Comment: returning [object object] is not an issue .Beacuse you are returning an html tag.so Its shows like that only

Comment: You possibly meant to do `leterArr.forEach(char => text.innerHTML += \`<span>${char} </span>\`)`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548134/mapping-over-array-returns-object-object

Comment: `{ char }` creates an object literal using shorthand property names. Just remove the `{}`

Comment: or better: `text.innerHTML = leterArr.map(char => \`<span>${char}</span>\`).join("")`

Comment: mplungjan, result still is the same I didnt get <span>A</span>, is <span>[Object object]</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React translate `{char}` to Object. So, when you concat it with string the object becomes `[Object object]`

use this

```
animation = () => {
  let text = document.querySelector(".hi");
  let leterArr = [...text.textContent];
  text.textContent = "";
  leterArr.map(char => {
    return (text.innerHTML += `<span>${char}</span>`)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
animation = () => {
  let text = document.querySelector(".hi");
  let leterArr = [...text.textContent];
  text.textContent = "";
  let temp;
  leterArr.map(char => {
    temp += "<span>" + char +"</span>"
  })
  text.innerHtml = temp;
}
```